# Looking For A jQuery Carousel Similar to Blizzard's

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I am looking for a jQuery carousel similar to the one on [Blizzard's homepage](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/) where it is centered, does not display the horizontal scroll bars even though the carousel's content is outside of the browser's width, supports image crossfading, and includes pagination.

I have played with SlidesJS and carouFredSel but these carousels are not compatable. After spending hours testing, I realized it is because these plug-ins rely on a having a fixed width for the container which causes the horizontal scroll bars to appear when the carousel is wider then the browser width.

I am wondering if there is a carousel that uses a similar code structure, and embeds the image as the background of the div via CSS:

```
<div id="carousel">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="content">Slide01</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="content">Slide02</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="content">Slide03</div>
  </div>
</div>

.carousel {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slide {}

.content {
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/1200x500 center top no-repeat;
  min-width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: for one, the blizzard slider is flash based. to get this to work with jquery you will have to do a jquery function to trigger on resize to get window width:
`$(window).resize(function(){var w = $(window).width(); $('#sliderContainer').css({width: w});});`

Comment: no problem, i will post as an answer instead of a comment for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for one, the blizzard slider is flash based. to get this to work with jquery you will have to do a jquery function to trigger on resize to get window width:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
       var w = $(window).width(); 
       $('#sliderContainer').css({width: w});
});
```

Comment: Also to add, another way around this is just to remove the scroll bars with jQuery by doing `$("body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");`.